# How to close numerous command line windows in a single click  from Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am running a Java program that connect 1000 clients to a server at a time, in command prompt. For each client a command line window will open.

How do I close each individual 1000 more windows from taskbar at a time?

Is there any method in Windows 7 to close a bulk of windows. (It is not a running process the window is appear after finished its run so we cannot close it from task manager)

If anybody can please help me, thanks in  advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do that from the taskbar but you can build small separate application that will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just kill the program with `taskkill /f /im java.exe` (or `javaw.exe`).

Comment: after finish  running process the program individual 1000 windows will appear in taskbar. i just want to close that all

Comment: Windows always belong to a process. Find out which one is responsible and act accordingly. Process Explorer can help you there, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows all are piled up under a single command prompt icon on the task bar, you can right click on the icon and select "Close all windows".

But seriously, 1,000 windows? You need to redesign that program.

Comment: sorry it is appeared as individual 1000 windows in taskbar.

Comment: @Amith The question is; why would you want that to be the case? And can't you fix that?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey i just testing ma server how much of connection it accept without any delay. after testing my program this closing process consumes much time

Comment: @Amith - A Windows window (and the process behind it) is a fairly heavy object. It's not surprising that closing 1,000 of them will take a long time. What is surprising is that Windows doesn't choke to death when you open all of them.

Comment: @Amith Which is why I would create a single client which open 1000 connections and shuts down when its finished. I would write it so it can be run from a test harness so there is no extra process to kill.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey no the each client is act as seperate thread. it is active am trying to close that all after my testing completed

Comment: A program can have 1000 threads with a client connection each and shut them down fairly easily.